# When to use rdd in Spark2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

With the new SparkSQL APIs, it seems that we don't need RDD anymore. Since RDD is expensive, it seems that we should avoid it. Can someone explain when is a good time to use RDD in Spark2?

Comment: Please see link below for more on custom partitioning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116294/custom-partitioner-in-pyspark-2-1-0/53844859#53844859

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it seems that we don't need RDD anymore

RDD API is more general and in fact is SQL API is build on top of RDD API with a bunch of extensions.

> Since RDD is expensive, it seems that we should avoid it.

RDD API is not inherently expensive. It just doesn't provide the same optimizations as SQL API. You can still build high performance applications on top of RDDs (check for example `org.apache.spark.ml`).

> Can someone explain when is a good time to use RDD in Spark2?

It is opinion based but if you need end-to-end type safety or work a lot with types, which don't have built-in encoders, RDD API is a natural choice.

You may prefer RDD when order of execution is important (you can create your own planner rules with SQL, but it is much more effort) or you need low level control (like user defined `Partitioners`).

Comment: A critical area where RDDs are better than Datasets/DataFrames is in iterative algorithms like you subtly referred to when discussing the spark ML package. Even though the Spark ML (not original RDD MLLib) APIs refer to Datasets, under the hood they tend to use RDDs then convert back to Datasets at the end. The Catalyst optimizer is not parallelized, so optimizing an iterative algorithm is impractical.

Comment: @Garren Can you elaborate on that, may be with an example? I though iterative algorithms are basically when you calculate something then put it in cache and access that data multiple times instead of just transforming it once and writing results. So why it would be less performant to do that calculation, of what you are going to put in cache, using Dataset?

Comment: @MaxNevermind Think for example about gradient descent, gradient boosting, LDA, KMeans or pretty much any graph algorithm. In regards of the last one you can use graphframes for comparisons.

Comment: Though "The RDD-based API is expected to be removed in Spark 3.0." https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: You should only use an RDD if you need fine-grained control over the physical distribution of data.**

This might not be relevant to Spark 2.0 and is probably relevant for Spark 2.2 and after. I found this in [Spark: The Definitive Guide](https://github.com/databricks/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide) and I found this section of the book helpful in deciding whether or not to use an RDD:

> There are basically no instances in modern Spark, for which you should
>   be using RDDs instead of the structured APIs beyond manipulating some
>   very raw unprocessed and unstructured data (p. 44).

If you decide that you absolutely need to use RDDs, you can refer to p. 212 in the book in the section on "When to use RDDs". Excerpt reproduced:

> In general, you should not manually create RDDs unless you have a
>   very, very specific reason for doing so. They are a much lower-level
>   API that provides a lot of power but also lacks a lot of the
>   optimizations that are available in the Structured APIs. For the vast
>   majority of use cases, DataFrames will be more efficient, more stable,
>   and more expressive than RDDs.
>
> The most likely reason for why you'll want to use RDDs is because you
>   need fine-grained control over the physical distribution of data
>   (custom partitioning of data). (p. 212)