# RDD pyspark partitionBy - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, partitioning

```
list_1 = [[6, [3, 8, 7]], [5, [9, 7, 3]], [6, [7, 8, 5]], [5, [6, 7, 2]]]

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list_1)
newpairRDD = rdd1.partitionBy(2,lambda k: int(k[0]))
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(newpairRDD.glom().collect()))
```

I want to partition by key.

I am getting

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partitioning function provided to `partitionBy` operates on the key of each entry of the RDD, i.e. the first element of each entry. So you're calling `lambda k: int(k[0])` on the integer keys, thus causing the error you encountered.

If you simply want to partition by key, your lambda function should be an identity operation, e.g.

```
newpairRDD = rdd1.partitionBy(2, lambda x: x)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the key should be an integer inside quotation marks like that

```
list_1 = [["6", [3, 8, 7]], ["5", [9, 7, 3]], ["6", [7, 8, 5]], ["5", [6, 7, 2]]]
```

That way, it works